# Importing 2d array of files

Tags: import

I would like to import multiple files to a 2d array.
I know to get a list of files I can do

```
myfiles=FileNames["*.txt"]
alldata=Import/@myfiles
```

Is it possible to get my data files in a 2d array if, for example, my files look like

```
myfiles={file11.txt,file12.txt,file21.txt,file22.txt}
```

where the numbers in the filenames correspond to an x and y index. 
I have done this using for loops. Is there a more functional way?

Comment: its best if your files end with .dat;  your command should work as is (?)

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I suggest the following: 
 1) As you receive help, try to give it too, by **answering questions** in your area of expertise. 
 2)[`Read the FAQs`](http://tinyurl.com/cacvex2)!  3) When you see good Q&A, vote them up by [`clicking 
the gray triangles`](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system 
is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge.  ALSO, remember to 
accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, 
[`by clicking the checkmark sign`](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t)`. Another suggestion: a nice user name?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A different interpretation:

Yes, it's possible and easy using `GatherBy`

```
myfiles = {"file11.txt", "file12.txt", "file21.txt", "file22.txt"};    
t = GatherBy[myfiles, {StringTake[#, -5] &}] // Transpose

(* ==> {{"file11.txt", "file12.txt"}, {"file21.txt", "file22.txt"}} *)

t[[1, 1]]

(* ==> "file11.txt" *)

t[[2, 1]]

(* ==> "file21.txt" *)

(* import with a double map*)
Function[fs, Import /@ fs] /@ t

(*or the much more elegant way of importing -- one just has to read the docs:) *)
Map[Import, t, {2}]
```

Comment: most probably the right one too ;-)

Comment: @chris Thanks :)

Comment: Yes, this is exactly what I wanted. Thanks